# converting Big Decimal(15,12) to string

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

Hi i'am having a input Big Decimal(15,12) value in source in output i am expecting that as string. For example, my source file with value 0.000000000000 by using tmap to convert it into string. "String.valueOf(column name)" for this im getting output is 0E-12. expected output is 0.0000000000 can anyone provide the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not applying any transformations to your `BigDecimal` column, you can just read it as a `String` from your file.
If you must read it as a `BigDecimal` and then format it to string, you can do this in your `tMap`:

```
new DecimalFormat("#0.000000000000").format(columnName)
```