# Data type conversation in talend

Tags: talend

Hi i'am having a input `Big Decimal(15,12)` value in source in output i am expecting that as string. For example, my source file with value **0.000000000000** by using tmap to convert it into string.

```
  "String.valueOf(column name)"
```

for this im getting output is **0E-12**. expected output is **0.0000000000** can anyone provide the solution?

Comment: You need to format the output from BigDecimal, e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269045/format-a-bigdecimal-as-string-with-max-2-decimal-digits-removing-0-on-decimal-p

Comment: Please see my answer to this very same question here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48725117/899863

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help

new BigDecimal("String value").setScale(12, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).toPlainString();